# App crashes if "play" button is not clicked

Tags: android

Ok I'm making a simple quiz trivia app in which user listens to the audio and guess the song. The problem I'm facing is that if the user clicks the "next" button without listing to the audio the app crashes which it shouldn't. and if the user listen to the audio and press pause and then click the "next" button it again crashes. It works well only when the user is listening to the audio select the option and click "next" without clicking the pause button. 
Here is the code

```
 private void setQuestionView()
{
    imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mp==null) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Lylevel3.this, R.raw.q11);
                mp.start();
                imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            }
            else{
                mp.pause();
                mp = null;
                imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            }
        }
    });

    if (qid == 1) {
        imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mp==null) {
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Lylevel3.this, R.raw.q12);
                    mp.start();
                    imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                }
                else{
                    mp.pause();
                    mp = null;
                    imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

There are 10 levels and each level has 5 questions. 
Next button code

```
    setQuestionView();

    butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.stop();
            mp = null;
            imagebutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER() + " " + answer.getText());

            if(answer.getText().equals(currentQ.getANSWER()))
            {
                score++;
                Log.d("score", "Your score" + score);
            }

            if(qid<5){
                currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                setQuestionView();
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(Lylevel3.this,                       ResultActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Also is there a reason you're setting v1.setOnClickListener twice in some scenarios?

Comment: You can use boolean flags to check whether he has played the music completely, and if he has then you can set it to true & vice versa for other condition.

Comment: First thing you should do is that you should use proper variable names related to their use. people can not understand that what is v1 ,v2  and what they are used for. USE PROPER FORMATTING.

Comment: you can use switch statement instead setOnClickListener . Why you set setOnClickListener multiple times ?

Comment: @kottary can you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: @intelliJAmiya that;s a good idea I will try that thanks :)

Comment: @Udil Actually I'm using multiple setOnClickListener like 5 times since new question appears on a separate activity. I will try using switch now

Comment: @hyeri try this way .Good luck

Comment: @hyeri can you add the code for the next button click listener??

Comment: @kottary sure.  I have edited the above code since I wasn't sure how to add the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the audio is paused mp will be null. So when you click on next button

mp.stop(); // this code will gives exception

so check before stopping, whether the instance is null or not:

if(mp != null)  {

mp.stop(); // and rest of your code

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't put below code inside a method/function

```
v1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickList)
{ ........
}
```

Comment: is there a reason behind that? I'm asking since this function displays the questions and I don't know where to use setOnClickListener besides that

Comment: Set Click listener on buttons in onCreate(). Create a method that handles the songs and when user click next e.g. the playSong method is called